# K9 not showing all mails in unified inbox

Tags: k9-mail

I noticed recently that K9 is showing emails in individual folders, but no longer in the Unified Inbox. That still exists but has had no new entry in the last few weeks.

I have changed nothing in configuration, although it is possible that I got a new version of K9 in a bulk update.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or how to get it working again?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the icons at the bottom of the screen. The middle of the five looks like three bars of different lengths:

```
-------
------
----
```

that is the sort key and I must have accidentally "pocket dialed it".

Sorting by date made it clear to me that all emails ***are*** being shown in the unified inbox.